# CSS: assigning fixed width div along with percent assigned divs for same parent.

Tags: html, css

I am writing a basic header for my website. Nothing fancy.  The fixed topbar should contain several sub divs.  I am having trouble getting the subdivs to manipulate their shape.  Below is an example of my code and a question which will help clear up this issue for me.

Thanks.

I have some basic html:

```
<div id="all">
    <div id="topbar">
        <div id="lnamePlate"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and some basic css:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

body {
    position: relative
}

#all {
    background-color: white;
    height: 4000px;
    width: 100%;
}

#topbar {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: 50;
}

#lnamePlate {
    position: relative;
    background-color: purple;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 55;
}
```

Why isn't the purple lnamePlate box 50% of the topBar width?  See my JSFiddle below for the error.

**EDIT**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbefus/vR3AF/132/)

Comment: I've made up a JSFiddle and it's working fine. What browser are you using? (posted in the edit)

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle of what I see currently. It looks like the purple rectangle is 50% of the yellow. http://jsfiddle.net/x7WLT/

Comment: I copied your code in a page in my local server and this is 50% exactly...
What is your problem now?

Comment: Work fine at me too.  Take a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/stryd3r/MvfjK/1/

Comment: You are all correct, I was posting a subsection of code from what I am working on.  It doesn't seem to be working with the rest of it.  I will attach a jsfiddle for the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem but will not work on IE :

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/vR3AF/146/

```
#rnamePlate {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: purple;
    height: 100%;
    width: -moz-calc(50% - 75px);
/* WebKit */
 width: -webkit-calc(50% - 75px);
/* Opera */
 width: -o-calc(50% - 75px);
/* Standard */
 width: calc(50% - 75px);
    right:0px;
    z-index: 55;
    top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

im sure it is 50% width percent :

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/vR3AF/130/

```
#lnamePlate {
    position: relative;
    background-color: purple;
    height: 50%;
    width:50%;
    z-index: 55;
}
```

i think you forgot adding `width:50%;` in your code.

Comment: I did have the width: statement before but it was not working... width: 50% works but what I had was width: 50% - 75px;  which does not work.  Any ideas why?

Comment: what do you mean by 50%-75px ??

Comment: ofcourse 50%-75px is not a valid css syntax , you can expalin what you want exactly , and i may help you.

Comment: Thanks man -- much appreciated. In the header I will have a 150px image in a centered div (logo with the & symbol over it) with words in the divs on either side  I want the two outer divs to be the width of the site while keeping the logo in the center.

Comment: oh so you want 3 divs , one in center with width of 150px , and two others on both sides depends on the windows size (i.e percent) , is this correct ?

Comment: this is a quick script solution till i figure a pure css solution . hope it helps : http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/vR3AF/134/

Comment: The problem will appear when you resize windows , we can handle this with little script but still pure css rocks

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid the js route.  I am in no way a web developer but minimizing js for styling seems optimal.  Thanks for that solution though, it helps.

Comment: i think the new answer is the best ;)